# Can pdf measure tool be used in winform or WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, winforms, pdf

Can the measure tool in pdf reader(adobe acrobat reader) be used in winForm/ wpf application?
By using which api does it can be achieved?

How to scale the pdf to the user input value?

If I want to display .tiff file in the same form then how to I do so. Means I want to make it compatible for both .pdf and .tiff file

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WinForms, yes you can embed the PDF Reader control, but I strongly recommend you don't. It locks you into a particular version, won't embed in a 64-bit app, and is unreliable.

It is much easier to use a `WebBrowser` control:

```
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(myPDFFilename)
```

To show different types of files, you'll need to write a little function:

```
  Sub ShowFileInWebBrowser(wb As WebBrowser, filename As String)
    Select Case System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename).ToLower
      Case ".pdf"
        wb.Navigate(filename)
      Case ".tif"
        Dim strHTML As String = "<html><img src='" & filename & "' /></html>"
        wb.DocumentText = strHTML
      Case Else
        Throw New ArgumentException
    End Select
  End Sub
```

To edit or inspect a TIF, use a `Graphics` object:

```
Dim img As Image = Bitmap.FromFile(strFilename)
Dim gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img)
```

You can get the real-world dimensions of the image as follows:

```
Dim strMessage As String = "Image size -  Height " & (img.Height / img.VerticalResolution).ToString & " inches, Width " & (img.Width / img.HorizontalResolution).ToString & " inches"
MsgBox(strMessage)
```

PDF is more difficult. You need to extract the images first, which will require a library. Aspose will do it, but it is not free. The PdfSharp free library cannot extract images reliably. Not sure if the free library iTextSharp can do it.

Comment: I have one more question. if we want to manipulate the data i.e. if we want to add line or any graphical entity to this file, can we do that?
Actually i want to calculate the length of this line which i have added and display that in file(similar like measure tool of pdf). Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Sounds like you are processing scanned images?

Comment: PDFsharp and iTestsharp creates a pdf and edits in that pdf file. But if we want to do same operation in winform like view the pdf and manipulate in that pdf viewer, Is that possible? To achieve this what we should do?

Comment: Editing a PDF is not easy, since the whole idea of PDF is to be an unchanging electronic document. I don't know of any WinForm control that allows you to edit a PDF within a WinForms app, sorry. If you are talking about PDFs that come from a document scanner, your best bet is to extract the images from the PDF and edit those

Comment: Actually i want to do the measure operation on this pdf/.tiff file. Like create a rectangle and calculate its area. Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: Sorry that's not a simple question to answer. You will need to use a PDF library to extract images to measure them. I checked and PDFSharp cannot do this reliably. You can try asking a new question to see if anyone else is able to help you more than I can

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to get the physical size of the image for the TIF

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me :)